# Return array of 5 or fewer objects that show the most popular books in a library popularity is determined by the amount of borrows a book has

Tags: javascript

I am still fairly new to Javascript so am trying my best here but I have not been successful in correcting my function to run properly, if you guys could help me here or at least point me in the right direction that would be great! I am trying to return an array of the top 5 books that are in my "library" popularity is determined by the number of borrows a book has, here is the prompt I am given to work with:

The `getMostPopularBooks()` function has a single parameter:

- An array of books.

It returns an array containing five objects or fewer that represents the most popular books in the library. Popularity is represented by the number of times a book has been borrowed.

Each object in the returned array has two keys:

- The `name` key which represents the title of the book.
- The `count` key which represents the number of times the book has been borrowed.

If more than five books are present, only the top five should be returned.

Here is the example provided:

```
getMostPopularBooks(books);/*
 [
{ name: "incididunt nostrud minim", count: 30 },
{ name: "culpa do sint", count: 30 },
{ name: "ullamco est minim", count: 29 },
...
]
*/
```

Here is a portion of the data provided:

```
const books = [{
id: "5f447132d487bd81da01e25e",
title: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna",
genre: "Science",
authorId: 8,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2cfa3e1d234679b9",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e1c71888e2233621e",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ede05a0b1e3394d8b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3900dfec59489477",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eed18105706d6ca19",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e5aa2bb5545a0f8a6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ea508b6a99c3e42c6",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e0b3e2ff72fc503e7",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e91c2af00cb74e82b",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e2f35653fa80bf490",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7b9cd304fed3a8bc",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed9aac23c0340aab2",
    returned: true,
  },
],},{
id: "5f4471329627160be1e8ce92",
title: "esse ea veniam non occaecat",
genre: "Classics",
authorId: 10,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed3609b719568a415",
    returned: false,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e7a1be21e362b82f9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e6059326d9feb9a68",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ec32d71dabec35b06",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e59f9380a1d03d766",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e141b97d842b680fd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e409f8883af2955dd",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee176f80b8d5d24da",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eef419207c5fa4ec9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4081699cdc6a2735",
    returned: true,
  },
],},{
id: "5f44713265e5d8d17789beb0",
title: "tempor occaecat fugiat",
genre: "Travel",
authorId: 16,
borrows: [
  {
    id: "5f446f2e4eff1030e7316861",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecc5c4787c403f844",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ee1661e64cde14e55",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e50cc2da9cd80efdb",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef795e593cd3cd19d",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2eae901a82e0259947",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e3e70bb4e1ab821c9",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ef2ab5f5a9f60c4f2",
    returned: true,
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2e136866e4fe60c893",
    returned: true,
  },
],}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function getMostPopularBooks(books) {
const bookPopularity = books.map((book) => book.title);
const temp = [];
bookPopularity.map((title) => {
const borrowLocation = temp.findIndex((element) => element.name === title);
if (borrowLocation >= 0) {
  temp[borrowLocation].count = temp[borrowLocation].count + 1;
} else {
  temp.push({ name: title, count: 1 });
}
});
temp.sort((alpha, delta) => delta.count - alpha.count);
if (temp.length > 5) {
return temp.slice(0, 5);
}
return temp;
}
```

Here is also the Testing code in case you guys are wanting to look at it:

```
describe("getMostPopularBooks()", () => {
it("should return an ordered list of most popular books", () => {
  const actual = getMostPopularBooks(books);
  const [first, second] = [
    { name: "sit eiusmod occaecat eu magna", count: 11 },
    { name: "ullamco est minim", count: 5 },
  ];
  expect(actual[0]).to.eql(first);
  expect(actual[1]).to.eql(second);
});

it("should limit the list to the top five", () => {
  const actual = getMostPopularBooks(books);
  expect(actual.length).to.equal(5);
});
});
```

I know I pass the second test "limit the list to the top five" but I do not pass the first test, I receive error that states "expected { Object (name, count) } to deeply equal { Object (name, count) }" Once again if you guys could help or point me in the right direction that would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've *massively* overcomplicated this...

```js
function getMostPopularBooks(books, count=5) {
    // organise book data
    const borrows = books.map(book=>({name:book.title, count:book.borrows.length}));
    // sort by borrow count, descending
    borrows.sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count);
    // return top N
    return borrows.slice(0,count);
}
```

Comment: @N.K. The returned array should, apparently, just have "name" and "count" keys.

Comment: Yes, my bad, saw that later, so deleted the comment.

Comment: `const borrows = books.map(book=>({name:book.title, count:book.borrows.length}));`

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks, I forgot that returning an object literal requires additional parentheses for disambiguation.